# Finding the sum of all elements of a sequence, ending with the number 0 using do-while loop in Java

Tags: java

I am a beginner. I appreciate if someone solves my problem in simple way in Java.

Problem:
Find the sum of all elements of a sequence, ending with the number 0.
The number 0 itself is not included into the sequence and serves as a sign of cessation.
Sample Input: 
3 
6 
8 
0 and
Sample Output: 
17

I am writing following program:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        do {
            sum += scanner.nextInt();
        } while (scanner.nextInt() != 0);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

And What I get is as following:

Input:
3
6
8
0

Output:

11 <---it should come out as 17.
Please figure out where the code is wrong.

Comment: You're calling twice nextInt (each one reads an int) so in fact you use 1 over 2

Comment: The construct `int i; while ((i = scanner.nextInt()) != 0) {}` would be better for the task at hand.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. @azro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem with your code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    do {
        sum += scanner.nextInt(); // consuming an int from keyboard with nextInt()
    } while (scanner.nextInt() != 0); // consuming another int from keyboard with nextInt()
    System.out.println(sum);
```

for input `3 6 8 0`

```
 sum += scanner.nextInt(); //this nextInt() consumes 3 now sum has 3
 scanner.nextInt() != 0 // this nextInt() consumes 6 but does not add to sum now sum has 3 only the 6 is ignored 

 sum += scanner.nextInt(); // same here this consumes 8 and add to sum now sum has 11 which is the output
 scanner.nextInt() != 0 // this nextInt() consumes 0 which fails the condition
```

In short you are ignoring every second input

**The fix**

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         int sum = 0;
         int num = 0;
         while((num = scanner.nextInt()) != 0) { // nextInt() is called only once and value is cashed in num
             sum += num; // add this num to sum
         }
         System.out.println(sum); // prints 17 as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int checker = 0;
        do {
            checker = scanner.nextInt();
            sum += checker;

        } while (checker != 0);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

In your code value coming from `scanner.nextInt()` in `while loop` is being missed to be added. That's causing a issue